# Open Bootstrap accordion panel from menu bar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

my menu put in header.html which will be loaded in all pages.

If I click the menu from index.html, it will open the corresponding accordion panel in product.html by using below js code (which place in the end of product.html markup ).

But if I click the menu from product.html, no respond from the accordion panel.
what wrong with my code?

```
$(function(){

// check if there is a hash in the url
if ( window.location.hash != '' )
{
    // remove any accordion panels that are showing (they have a class of 'in')
    $('.collapse').removeClass('in');

    // show the panel based on the hash now:
    $(window.location.hash + '.collapse').collapse('show');
}
```

});

header.html

```
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default menu" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle menu-item" data-toggle="dropdown">Products
                        <b class="caret"></b>
                    </a>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="product.html#collapse1">product A</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-li" wp-loop-skip>
                                        <a href="product.html#collapse2"> product B</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="menu-li" wp-loop-skip>
                                        <a href="product.html#collapse3"> product C</a>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can actually add that directly to the link: e.g. `<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">Toggle first element</a>`

Comment: @SachiTekina  not work after add this code if I click the link from index.html